# Python-style variables in C++

Tags: python, c++, types, type-safety, strong-typing

I'm working on a C++ project and am trying to figure out how to make a "dynamic" variable.

In Python, variables can have multiple types:

```
variable = 0
variable = "Hello"
```

In Java, this is also (somewhat) achievable:

```
Object o = 0;
o = "Hello";
```

From what I can find related to C++, there is no `object` type or "dynamic" object at that.

The reason I need this, is I'm trying to create an object which takes in any of the following types:
`int`, `float`, `char`, `string`, `bool`, and allow me to do operations such as:

```
object o = 0; // currently an int
o -= 2.5; // now a float
o += "Test"; // now a string
```

Is there any default functionality for this kind of variable? If not, can it be done with macros, `struct`'s, etc.?

I've found things like this:

```
template <typename name>
```

But have no idea how to use it.

Comment: C++17 will have `std::any` which is exactly what you want. Right now, you can use `boost::any` or roll your own implementation out. However, this is not dynamic, exactly.

Comment: @user2296177 I'm working with C++11 and am hoping (but am happy to drop support if not possible) to have backwards compatibility. I'm useless with C++, could you please give me an example? I have no idea where to begin...

Comment: You can always create a class which will have vectors of all types you want to support and then add an interface to it. But this on the face of it seems like a very bad idea in terms of maintainability and readability. I would think about implementing something like this very hard and try to come up with an entirely different solution.

Comment: @mirosval I was thinking of doing that, except come across the fact that I'm probably going to need to expand it later on for an infinite amount of object types.

Comment: Why do you need to assign different types to the variable in the first place?

Comment: @mirosval I'm creating a compiler that allows any type to be applied to a variable and edited as the user wishes.

Comment: What you could do is have a struct that stores an object type as well as a pointer to that object. Then you can store anything in the value and it can be cast to the correct type when it needs to be accessed. Try looking up how Python does this in https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/structures.html

Comment: @mirosval Would this `object type` be dynamic?

Comment: Somethng like `o -= 2.5; o += "Test"` wouldn't even run on Python. PHP maybe ...

Comment: @Matthias Just a critical example. Changing an integer to a float and then to a string wouldn't be normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [boost.variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html) library. Basic usage instructions [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic). In short, it would be something like

```
using var_t = boost::variant<bool,int,double,string, boost::blank_t>;
var_t var = "hello";
std::cout << boost::get<std::string>(var) << '\n';
std::cout << var << '\n'; // if all possible stored types are streamable
```

Somewhat non-straightforward part is accessing value without knowing the exact type. This requires [static visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html).

In case you wonder what the difference is between `any` and `variant` - you are not alone, and [here is the comparison chart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't know how to implement these things coming from an all Java/Python background.

Comment: I don't know anything but this might help, if you're not familiar with c++ : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html . What you found about templates is not what you look for.

Comment: :O Boost is platform dependent!

Comment: @frayment - you will unlikely experience any platform dependent behavior or problems with libraries like `variant`

Comment: `boost::variant` doesn't have a `get` method, did you mean `boost::get`?

Comment: Uhh.. So I just downloaded it and am trying it now... Do I really have to use the 100MB worth of files? I don't want my project to be any bigger than it already has to be.

Comment: @frayment - most `boost` libraries (`variant` inclusive) are "header only", which means that once compiled your binary/library will only have what it's using and you won't have any additional runtime dependencies. But you do need the boost/include directory on the hard disk, that's the price you pay :)

Comment: @bobah Ah! Lovely. Thankyou for the info. I just visited GitHub and saw they have a "detached" version of JUST variant. I'll try this out now.

Answer (score 3):

Every language has its own idiomatic constructs, and you should **not** try to mimic Python code in C++. As said by @user2296177 , the closest C++ tool (in current version) is boost::any, which is also included in C++17 as std::any.

But even boost:any has some limitations: types assigned to a boost::any must be copy constructibles, and their destructor must never throw exceptions.

If you only need to accept a known list of types, you can use good old (coming from C) unions or their boost automatic equivalent boost::variant.

But in fact, you should wonder why you need that, how you intend to keep track of actual type, whether you need to allow casting or aliasing. Because beyond the dynamic Python variables, C++ allows to either convert or alias between types.

TL/DR: do not try to mimic a Python idiom and carefully analyze what is your real need. A union could be the tools in some use cases, a void pointer in some others or a dedicated struct could be necessary. It really depends on the real use case.

Comment: The issue I have, is that I am **potentially** taking in **any** type of object. I'm designing the program as to **not** track the type at all, but rather apply operations to the variable directly and print results upon request.

Comment: @Serge - AST parsing is a valid use case for `variant`/`any` in C++, tag-type-value protocols parsing sometimes too. Whatever results in cheaper/readable/fast (whichever the priority is) code is a good solution, no matter what the language is, IMHO.

Comment: @frayment: What are the operations that are common to all the types you want to process? And do you want to process only custom types (could derive from one single interface) or also standard types (string, list, map) or even intrinsics (int, float, char)? And is the list of allowed types limited or not?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Operations: `+-*/% += -= *= /= %= == = &= |= ^= ~= <<= >>= << >> &|^~`. And I need both custom types **and** primitives. The list is somewhat open at this stage.